# ASP.Net Core WebAPI - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I'm encountering an issue with CORS while using **`IAsyncResourceFilter`** implementation.
I want to be able to call my actions from other domains as well...

I've defined the CORS policy under my `Startup` file as the following:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin();
    });
});
```

And under the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

It works fine without using a **`TypeFilterAttribute`** which use **`IAsyncResourceFilter`**.

For example calling my API action without any `TypeFilterAttribute` attribute works:

```
public bool Get()
{
    return true;
}
```

But when adding my `TypeFilterAttribute` as follows it doesn't work and returns the error about the CORS:

```
[MyTypeFilterAttribute("test")]
public bool Get()
{
    return true;
}
```

Anything I'm missing? What should I add when using `IAsyncResourceFilter`?

The following is the `MyTypeFilterAttribute` code: (With no real logic...)

```
public class MyTypeFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public MyTypeFilterAttribute(params string[] name) : base(typeof(MyTypeFilterAttributeImpl))
    {
        Arguments = new[] { new MyTypeRequirement(name) };
    }

    private class MyTypeFilterAttributeImpl: Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
    {
        private readonly MyTypeRequirement_myTypeRequirement;

        public MyTypeFilterAttributeImpl(MyTypeRequirement myTypeRequirement)
        {
            _myTypeRequirement= myTypeRequirement;
        }

        public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            context.Result = new OkResult();

            await next();
        }
    }
}

public class MyTypeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public MyTypeRequirement(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ehm... how about posting the content of your type filter?

Comment: Added the code. Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you also add a `[EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins")]` attribute to your method?

Comment: Will this `context.Result = new OkResult();` not just clear any headers set?

Comment: @poke this doesn't work as well...

Comment: @Mardoxx That should [only set the status code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/StatusCodeResult.cs).

Comment: @Mardoxx amazing... Removing the OKResult line indeed solves my issue. This should be the answer... Thanks a lot!

Comment: You sure that is the solution, see what @poke said..?

Comment: It indeed solves my issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cors middleware sets headers on the response result object.

I believe you are resetting these with `context.Result = new OkResult();`

See poke's reply below. If you set any result in an action filter, this result gets sent back immediately, thus overwriting any other one!

Comment: Found it! There is indeed some logic [in the pipeline](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ControllerActionInvoker.cs#L399) that makes the pipeline stop early. Note that this checks for `Result != null`, so you cannot assign anything to `Result` and `Result` will be `null` initially, so you cannot assign anything inside of it either. This means that you cannot impact the result if you want the pipeline to continue.

Comment: Ahh there we go! Thanks :)